# Unable to reload JQGrid with new json data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am unable to reload JQGrid with new json data, which is received from a controller. In the code shown below, I display an alert after successfully  receiving data and also passing it to another method. However I am unable to refresh the data. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Code:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/TodoList/searchdata',
    traditional: true,
    dataType:"json",
    data: d,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));                 
        callme(data);
    }
})
```

### call me function:-

```
function callme(newone1) {
    $grid.jqGrid('clearGridData');
    $grid.jqGrid({
        //autowidth: true,
        caption: "Evaluated URLs",
        colNames: ["AccountName", "BU", "Salesop", "Isdormant"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "AccountName", align: "center", title: false, width: 400, resizable: false, sortable: false },
            { name: "BU", width: 125 },
            { name: "Salesop", align: "center", width: 125, sorttype: "date" },
            { name: "Isdormant", align: "center", width: 125, sorttype: "date" }
        ],
        data: newone1,
        datatype: 'json',
        emptyrecords: "0 records found",
        multiselect: true,
        localReader: {
            page: function (obj) {
                return (obj.page === 0 || obj.page === undefined) ? "0" : obj.page;
            }
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var ts = this;
            if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                $(this).hide();
                emptyMsgDiv.show();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                emptyMsgDiv.hide();
            }
        },
        height: "auto",
        sortname: "created",
        toppager: true,
        pager: "#url-pager",
        viewrecords: true
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    //$grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',
    //{    
    //    datatype: 'json',
    //    data: newone1
    //}).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
}
```

[image: Json data received is showing in an alert]

Answer (score 1):

You can reload `jqgrid` with new data. In your `ajax` success just do like the following.

```
var $grid=$('#your_grid_id');
$grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'local', data: data }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/9yxumygp/)

Comment: Could you please let me know is my json format correct?

Comment: Compare your new data with previously loaded data. @Baji